# Can you change a link title by named title attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, title

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible (and if so how) to change a link's color by polling the title attribute.  I'm working with an HTML page that is generated from another script that creates a accordion list of hyperlinks.  A couple of those hyperlinks I'd like to highlight, and I believe I can shoehorn in some JavaScript to do this (and the title attribute is the only unique element I can rely on), but I'm not sure how to write it.   Here's what a bit of the list page looks like:

```html
<div class="AccordionPanel AccordionPanelOpen">
    <div class="AccordionPanelTab">
    Forms
    </div>
        <div class="AccordionPanelContent" style="height: auto; display: block;">
            <ul class="arrows searchSubtype">
               <li class=""> 
                  <a title="Form-1.doc" target="_top" href="../Form-1.doc">
                  Form 1
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li class=""> 
                  <a title="Form-2.doc" target="_top" href="../Form-2.doc">
                  Form 2
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li class=""> 
                  <a title="Form-3.doc" target="_top" href="../Form-3.doc">
                  Form 3
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li class=""> 
                  <a title="Form-4.docx" target="_top" href="../Form-4.docx">
                  Form 4
                  </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use the attribute selector:

```
$("a[title='Form-4.docx']").css("color","red");
```

Comment: Thanks tymeJV. Seems like this should work, though I haven't gotten it to yet.  I'm now trying to determine if it's not working or if it's just being overridden.  There's so much going into generating this page it's really hard to tell who's on first.

Comment: @Etherplain -- `console.log()` statements everywhere! Try to map out when things are loading.

Comment: I was trying to use firebug for that very purpose.  Looking at the structure though, this addition should be loading last (at least among the .js files).  I'm wondering though if the CSS is the problem, especially if it has an !important declaration.